# What are the differences between the Spider-Man and Amazing Spider-Man universes?

Tags: the-amazing-spider-man, spider-man-trilogy, spider-man, comic-adaptation

Sam Raimi's *Spider-Man* trilogy was rebooted when Sony released *Amazing Spider-Man*, and part of this reboot were changes in the in universe story and world. Peter starts dating Gwen Stacy instead of Mary Jane, for example. What are the differences between the two universes?

I'm not looking for a scene-by-scene nit picky rundown here, but rather the larger, broad-stroke differences between the two settings/stories.

Comment: For a start: http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/3251/49, http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/9684/49 and http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/8168/49.

Comment: Are you also after the differences in the source universes those are based on (if any) and some deeper considerations of the different comic storylines those were adapted from (if any) or just the basic movie differences (as shown to us and easily listable by viewing the movies frame by frame)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's a quick rundown of the changes so far.

### Spider-Man

- In Sam Raimi's Spider-Man, the web shooters are organic mutations that were a result of the genetically engineered spider bite.
- In Amazing Spider-Man, they stuck to the comic book roots and had Peter invent mechanical web shooters that use a formula partly developed by his father.

### Peter's Past History

- In Sam Raimi's Spider-Man, Peter's parents are dead but we have no other information on them.
- In Amazing Spider-Man, Peter's parents death was part of a conspiracy concotted by OsCorp.

### The Osborns

- In Sam Raimi's Spider-Man, Norman Osborn wears a mechanical suit to become the Green Goblin.
- In Amazing Spider-Man, Harry Osborn is biologically transformed into the Green Goblin.

### Peter's Love Life

- In Sam Raimi's Spider-Man, Peter's first girlfriend is Mary Jane Watson. Gwen Stacy appears later on to complicate matters a bit but MJ remains his primary love interest.
- In Amazing Spider-Man, they once again stayed loyal to the comics and had Gwen Stacy be Peter's first love. Mary Jane was slated to appear in a minor role, but she was ultimately cut. Spidey's off/on lover from the comics Felicia Hardy makes an appearance as well.

### Misc

- In Sam Raimi's Spider-Man, the Daily Bugle and it's publisher J Jonah Jameson are featured heavily.
- In Amazing Spider-Man, the Daily Bugle starts to appear in the second movie but Jameson has not made an appearance yet, although he is mentioned.

Comment: @SystemDown - In addition to his suit, Norman Osborn is also biologically changed in a special chemical gas chamber.

Comment: Few more point: Uncle Ben  never user that classy line "With great power.....", uncle's killer's story is different. Betty Brant is not there in ASM etc

Comment: The Amazing Spider-man movie is closer to the Ultimate Spider-Man comics, while Raimi's is closer to main/616 spider-man.

Answer (score -4):

It appears to be that instead of having the origin story being linked to the Green Goblin, they linked it with the Lizard. Also, Peter is still in high school and his love is Gwen Stacy. Gwen's father also dies in this movie whereas he never dies in the 3rd Sam Raimi movie. Harry is also nowhere to be seen until the sequel. Jameson has not made appearance either.

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV! You're likely getting downvoted as your answer is very simplistic and doesn't explicitly describe the differences asked for in the question. Look at the other answer posted to get an idea of the sort of answer that is being looked for.

Comment: Thanks for your kind welcome and I will be more careful.