# What are the key differences between Christopher Nolan's batman character and Zack Snyder's batman character?

Tags: character, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice, comic-adaptation

I'm a huge Batman fan. Recently while binge watching the Batman series, a thought came across my mind as **what are the key differences between Christopher Nolan's batman and Zack Snyder's batman?**

Now I heard that Nolan did some working on the character and gave his story some modifications, but I'd like to know what are the differences between these two?

Comment: i dont get it.! How is this question **too broad**? Two different directors have their own take on the character and I'm specifically asking the **key** differences.! And for the sake of not long answers, I'm also fine with links or articles. This was a shock for me!
Take this question for example - http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/18929/what-are-the-differences-between-the-spider-man-and-amazing-spider-man-universes

Comment: The original version of your question contained `Any points, opinions, articles all are welcome.` which makes it clearly broad. However, I have removed that part and voted to reopen. Try not to add these words in other questions.

Comment: @Trivedi: Any answer to this question will be strongly opinionated. It's hard to get a fact based, subjective answer to this. Had you been asking for specifics, say difference in their suits or equipment this question wouldn't have been too broad. Hope this helps in understanding the deficits in your question in its current form.

Comment: @AJ that I'd written so that people could paste links and avoid long answers.. But you've got a point, will keep that in mind.

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher ya, as in their thinking, gadgets, etc. Nolan's batman was kinda first retired then came back, got rejected by the one he loved.. while Zack's batman had a different story. *(i've heard that BvS was at a later time)*

Comment: Is it worth doing community answers for each aspect? I.e. **Batsuit** / **Themes** / **Gadgets** etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are some key differences between Nolan's and Snyder's Batman.

1. Nolan's Batman is anti-gun. He didn't use guns to kill bad guys. IIRC, he didn't kill any. In case of Snyder's Batman, it's opposite. We can see him using guns when he tries to kill Superman.
2. We see many gadgets used by both versions of Batman, but Snyder's Batman got more sophisticated and more high-tech gadgets. You can also see that suit of Snyder's Batman is different.
3. That well where young Bruce fell in was behind Wayne Mansion, but in BvS, it is somewhere else. Same goes for graves of Bruce's parents.
   Nolan's Batman retired first and then came back, but it is not shown in BvS because it is set many years later than Nolan's Dark Knight trilogy.

Besides this, Gordan, who was a recurring character in Nolan's Dark Knight trilogy, doesn't appear in BvS.

But (Credits to @AnkitSharma) J.K. Simmons is [selected for this role](http://in.ign.com/justice-league-of-america/99781/news/justice-league-first-look-at-jk-simmons-as-commissioner-gord) which means this character will appear in future films. There is also robin costume in Batcave with joker graffiti on it and in Suicide Squad, it was clear that it belongs to dead robin. So this Snyder's Batman also had sidekick in past which was not in Nolan's Batman except John Blake.

Comment: [J.K. Simmons already selected for playing Police Commissioner James Gordon](http://in.ign.com/justice-league-of-america/99781/news/justice-league-first-look-at-jk-simmons-as-commissioner-gord) in future films, There is robin costume in batcave with joker graffiti on it and from suicide squad it's confirm that it belongs to dead robin. So this new batman also had sidekick in past which were not in nolan's batman except john blake